# Customize ServiceStack HTML format

Tags: servicestack

I'd like to customize the HTML5 result format used by ServiceStack. My basic goal is to be able to embed REST-style links between resources and to recognize them in-line. E.g., I'd like to be able to embed a `link rel="edit"`-type element in my response and convert that into the appropriate link/form/etc. when it's rendered. I have several other similar customizations in mind as well.

Would it be easier to build a static site off to the side that calls the JSON APIs? If not, how should I proceed with customizing the existing format? I think I can address my immediate need if I can supply my own CSS/JS, but I'm interested in any other extension points I might be overlooking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only limited customization available in the [HtmlFormat](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/Formats/HtmlFormat.cs) itself e.g. `TitleFormat`, `HtmlTitleFormat`, etc (see impl for details).

The body of the HtmlFormat is an embedded resource so ships inside the ServiceStack dll. To [customize any embedded resource in ServiceStack](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Metadata-page#updating-html-and-metadata-page-templates) you can just add the embedded file in the same directory structure as it is in ServiceStack project, to your Host project (which takes precedence).

To override the body, add a customized version of [HtmlFormat.html](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/Templates/HtmlFormat.html) in:

```
/Templates/HtmlFormat.html
```

Otherwise you can just completely remove it and add your own, e.g:

```
Plugins.RemoveAll(x => x is HtmlFormat);
Plugins.Add(new MyNewHtmlFormat());
```

Comment: This will definitely get me started. Is there any chance that a future version might allow for customizing the HTML `head` element? I think I am going to pretty much end up reimplementing the body just to replace a few elements in the head.

Comment: The fastest way to make what you want happen is to send a pull-req with what you need :) Here's the HtmlFormat.cshtml that gets embedded: https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/WebHost.Endpoints/Formats/HtmlFormat.html - feel free to add another HeadTemplate section.

Comment: Would you prefer to see something like `public static string[] HeadLinkElements { get;set;}` or `public static string HeadLinkElements { get; set;}`? The latter would be like doing string.Join on the former.

Comment: Note: The least invasive and most flexible Api is just a single string property, i.e. HeadHtml = ...

Comment: Thanks, just as a note, I ended up implementing my own format using that one as a base. If you are interested, I can clean it up and contribute it as an addition to the current format. The specific feature looks for a property on the response model like this: `operations: [ { method: "GET", operation: "details", path: "/objs/2134/details" } ]` and renders the appropriate UI, allowing you to have lightweight links between resources in a REST-ish way.

Comment: Sure, I was actually planning to add auto-linking by convention to the HTML Report format, would definitely be interested to see what you ended up with. A pull-request with your new class would be the easiest way for me to check it out, thx.

Comment: old post, but we do this via a customized ATOM format, where each object in the response is "syndicated" and contains navigation links in an opensearch spec.  Rather than decorate the models, we went after the Request objects.

Comment: @WarrenP No it's still valid. I've updated the link to the latest class.

Comment: HtmlTemplate is not a public instance property in HtmlFormat, that I can see.

Comment: @WarrenP Yeah that can now be customized by [overriding the Embedded Resource](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Metadata-page#updating-html-and-metadata-page-templates). I've modified the answer to include this.

Comment: That is a good change. I'm evalulating this as the basis for my company's entire RESTful service architecture, and I think this is the best thing out there, much less surface area and easier to grok than EF7+ASP.NET MVC5, and obviously Leagues Better than WCF which is Rubbish.  Hopefully this can be made to work on DNX/Linux at some point in the future.  For now, Mono is good.

Comment: @WarrenP thx, minimal complexity / conceptual overhead are core goals. IMO MS fx's has a tendency to come up with over-architected/complicated slns for what could be easily served by simpler/elegant slns. We'll look into DNX after v1.0 is shipped, atm it has too much churn and incomplete .NET Framework API's.